# Is there a shortcut in ColdFusion for converting undefined value to empty string?

Tags: syntax, coldfusion

I find myself writing code like this in ColdFusion a lot:

```
<cfset inputval = "" />
<cfif IsDefined("Form.Releases")>
    <cfset inputval = Form.Releases />
</cfif>
```

This is very cumbersome.  I just want an undefined value to be converted to an empty string.  Is there any kind of shortcut?

For example, in PHP I do this with strval function, i.e.:

```
$inputval = strval($_POST['Releases']);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out cfparam

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/6.1/htmldocs/tags-b13.htm

```
<cfparam name="Form.Releases" default="">
<cfset inputval = Form.Releases />
```